# Scaffold-Dbcontext failed - The server was not found or was not accessible

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework-core, .net-7.0

I have created a database using SQL Server Management Studio v18. My authentication method is set to SQL Server authentication.

I am trying to run `Scaffold-Dbcontext` command from the Package manager console like this:

```
Scaffold-DbContext "Password=dummy;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=dummy;Initial Catalog=SomeDB;Encrypt=false;Data Source=DESKTOP-MYDESKTOP" 
        -tables MyTable Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer 
        -OutputDir CompanyEntities
```

Although my credentials are correct, I get the following error:

> Network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)

I checked my server `sp_configure 'remote access'` value and it was set to 0 (which is correct for my case)

Environment:

- `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore` 7.0.0
- `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer` 7.0.0
- .NET 7